# I have function but in firebug console it says its not a function where I am calling it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

I am using a function in two sites but when I want to implement it to third site it does not work. When I look into firebug console it says its not a function. My function is in a separate file called profilter.js look like this:

```
jQuery.fn.sfProductFilter = function (options) {
    options = options || {};
    return this.each(function () {
        var pf = new SFProductFilter(this, options)
    })
}
```

and I am calling it from a page and code is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            console.log($("ul.productSmall"));
            $('ul.productSmall').sfProductFilter(); //says not a function.
});
```

I have checked through console.log followings
1- jQuery is included already
2- If I console.log from the js file it works but inside any code block it does not
3- ul.productSmall shows right results in console.log

I can provide link of site but just not providing it so moderator wont thinks its a spam.

I have struggled a lot please let me know where I am making mistake?

[image: console look like]

Comment: reset the browser cache and try again , check if script is actually loading

Comment: how to check script is loading?

Comment: sfProductFilter or SFProductFilter is not a function?

Comment: Firebug > Net [Tab] > All[sub tab] ,reload page or more spcifically Firebug > Net [Tab] > Js[sub tab]

Comment: I checked it and it says 304 Not Modified infront of my script... what does that mean?

Comment: Add some `console.log` on the line before the `jQuery.fn.sfProductFilter = ` line, see if that output comes before or after the `console.log($("ul.productSmall"));` you already have.

Comment: @DCoder I just do it and it comes before console.log($("ul.productSmall"));

Comment: I think at this point nobody will mind if you actually provide the site URL.

Comment: You are including jQuery twice, the second load happens far below the inclusion of profilter.js and destroys your custom function.

Comment: @DCoder Yes this works, can you put in answer so I can make accept it and vote it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Copied from [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10039129/i-have-function-but-in-firebug-console-it-says-its-not-a-function-where-i-am-cal#comment12842943_10039129).)

You are including jQuery twice, the second load happens far below the inclusion of profilter.js and destroys your custom function.

Comment: This!  It's very common when you're working with frameworks (like WP, Drupal, etc) that they include jQuery. So when you add your own jQuery include, one overwrites the other.  You should always use var $myJQ = jQuery.noConflict(); then add your extensions to $myJQ.  This will ensure you don't run into issues like this when working with larger code bases.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the jquery ui script?  Looks like .button() is called in

```
function myChecks(){
    $("#checkboxcontainer input[type='checkbox']").button();
}
```

I have a hunch this will do the trick.

Comment: in console it says:
$("ul.productSmall").sfProductFilter is not a function
[Break On This Error]
$('ul.productSmall').sfProductFilter();

Comment: is your script being included before or after jQuery? where is jQuery.fn.sfProductFilter = function (options) {
    options = options || {};
    return this.each(function () {
        var pf = new SFProductFilter(this, options)
    })
}
 called?

Comment: hopefully once you include the jQuery UI this may fix itself

Comment: Yes you are right but real problem was I was including jQuery twice --- Thanks for your effort and pointing out jQueryUI issue as well